# Can Hazelcast be used as a cache for *perl* web apps?

Tags: java, perl, hazelcast

I am looking at quickly implementing a hazelcast in-memory cache for a web application.

The web application is written in perl...

...so is there a way to access a hazelcast Map via perl?

Or, in worst case, must I write a thin hazelcast client in java, and call that from perl?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [`Cache::Memcached`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache%3a%3aMemcached) as [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hazelcast/FlEQKphhX0U/cafOoIjXHIQJ) to the hazelnut google groups seems to imply that someone else has already done this using this module.

For other solutions, you could continue searching on [`cpan for Memcache`](https://metacpan.org/search?q=memcache).  Or for a non distributed solution, can just go with the core library [`Memoize`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html).

Answer (score 0):

If there a memcached client for Perl? If so you can use the memcached protocol to connect to Hazelcast.

Chris

Comment: Thanks noctarius. I accepted Millers answer since he gave some specific links.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast could be used through its [REST Api](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#rest-client) so you need a JVM with Java library to support this feature.

Comment: Thanks efernandez. I shall look at the memcached option first. Rest is also another possibility, thank you.